# setting nginx reverse-proxy server on docker network 502 error

Tags: docker, api, http, nginx, reverse-proxy

```
localhost(web-browser) - docker_nginx(frontend static files) - docker_api_server
```

I set docker network like below

```
nginx server : port mapped with localhost {PORT_NGINX_SERVER}:{PORT_NGINX_SERVER}
nginx server has static files set as root : nginx is frontend server
nginx server should proxy path /api to API_SERVER
```

below is 502 error message from web-browser console

```
domain: localhost:{PORT_NGINX_SERVER}
request: GET /api/path
```

below is 502 error message from nginx container

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, 
client: 172.25.0.1 (from browser - docker network gateway), 
server: localhost (nginx container), 
request: "GET /api/path HTTP/1.1",
upstream: "http://172.25.0.6:{API_SERVER_PORT}/api/path",
host: "localhost:{PORT_NGINX_SERVER}", 
referrer: "http://localhost:{PORT_NGINX_SERVER}/react_route_path"
```

here I set {PORT_NGINX_SERVER}, {PORT_API_SERVER} to understand quickly (not on real config file)

```
server {
    listen       {PORT_NGINX_SERVER};
    server_name     localhost;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location /api {
        proxy_pass      http://{API_SERVER_DOMAIN}:{PORT_API_SERVER}/api;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        #proxy_set_header Origin "";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-Pcol HTTP;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_buffers 64 4k;
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 128k;
    }
    # ignore cache frontend
    location ~* (service-worker\.js)$ {
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        expires off;
        proxy_no_cache 1;
    }
}
```

is it correct I set? why 502 error shown?

- I did CORS setting on API server also
- I also set nginx nameserver as docker's embedded server correctly.
- all docker containers on same docker network

Comment: what about changing `localhost` to your host machine IP?

Comment: hi, thanks for reply, I tried to set server name as nginx container name on docker network. and only server name is changed on error message. localhost shown on host, refferrer field still..

Comment: First try running just nginx, then basic config (like port change) to your docker image if that works. Then go for reverse proxy.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to refer frontend web server status. frontend built static files works well on nginx. only reverse-proxy issue I have. should I remove this block?                               location ~* (service-worker\.js)$ {
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        expires off;
        proxy_no_cache 1;
    }